# Where are OpenSSL dll files stored?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, openssl

I wrote and app with Qt for Windows and Linux and I am using some dll's from OpenSSL. I am testing my app on two windows 10 machines and on one it works perfectly fine but on the other I get an error the app can't find `libeay32.dll`.

The app that works is loading `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` but I don't know from where it is getting them. I uninstalled OpenSSL 64 and OpenSSL 32. And I renamed `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` to `_libeay32.dll` and `_ssleay32.dll` in `Git\mingw64\bin`, `Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin`, `Windows\System32`, and `Windows\SysWOW64`.

The app still works but I have no idea why. Where else could OpenSSL store the dll files if they don't appear with `dir /s *libeay32/dll`? or how can I find out from where the app is loading the dlls?

Comment: You probably need [How to check for DLL dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7378959) or [How do I detect the DLLs required by an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/362560) Also see [Installing and registering win32 OpenSSL libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/906310).

Comment: *"... how can I find out from where the app is loading the dlls..."* - On the working machine, use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx). From the *View* menu, enable *Show Lower Pane*; then from the *View* menu Lower Pane, select *DLLs*. [Where to install shared DLLs on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2677808) may also be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for DLL dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) utility. It can to locate the all dll dependencies of your application.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find it with it